# https://gonum.org/v1/gonum Not Found

Tags: go, glide-golang

gonum.org/v1/gonum is not being recognized as a go package.
glide get gonum.org/v1/gonum is erroring out

> $> go get gonum.org/v1/gonum
>   can't load package: package gonum.org/v1/gonum: no Go files in /home/binet/dev/go/gocode/src/gonum.org/v1/gonum

Answer (score -1):

gonum.org/v1/gonum is not a package but a filesystem hierarchy which represents a group of packages that are grouped on the basis of the authors' identities.

With glide this will still fail for which the workaround is

> glide mirror set https://gonum.org/v1 https://github.com/gonum